# How to use tensorflow C API with cl compiler in Windows Comand prompt

Tags: c++, visual-studio, tensorflow, visual-c++, cl

I have downloaded the tensorflow.dll and include files for windows from the [tensorflow site](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/lang_c)

I only got a .dll file and the header files.

I want to test it using the simple code given on the same page, just printing the tensorflow version number.

I tried compiling with

```
cl /EHsc try.c /Iinclude /link lib\tensorflow.dll
```

but it doesnt work.
I discovered that I need a .lib file for it to work. Where or How do I get or generate the .lib file using the cl compiler in the command line?

Comment: And there is no information about installation/usage under Windows on tensorflow‘s homepage?

Comment: yeah no information about how to install in windows. only thew mac and linux is given